# Is it possible to destroy UFO walls using only Heavy Cannon and grenades?

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

I shot down a large scout, eliminated aliens outside, and came inside to see this: crash damage has destroyed a portion of 1st floor floor, so when I use the elevator to go up a level and pass through the door I just fall back down.

What are my options? Can I destroy the UFO walls to get at the remaining aliens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regular UFO Walls (and floors) have a damage rating of 80. According to [UFOPaedia](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Destroying_Terrain), Heavy Cannon(AP) can only deal up to 42 damage (which is unlikely, since the range is 25-75% normal damage) to terrain, and grenades deal 25 damage (and only to the center space).

The way terrain destruciton works, is that if a weapon deals more damage than the terrain's damage rating, it will become damaged / destroyed. This is a hard threshold, and it must be breached for *each* attack if you want to inflict terrain damage at all.

So unfortunately, the UFO appears unassailable, at least with your current equipment.

Fortunately, there is no penalty for leaving a UFO recovery mission. If you can't coax the aliens to come out to die, just load up all the corpses, weapons, and artifacts lying around the mission site back into your strikecraft... and leave. You'll miss out on recovered UFO parts, but that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Warning: Spoiler alert:

In most cases, I wouldn't use this (it makes the game much easier and significantly less 'X-Com-ey', but in your situation I'd probably allow it.

> After a certain number of turns (I believe around 40? Not sure), the aliens will leave the craft and begin search-and-destroy. You can kill them as they leave.

Comment: I believe it's actually 20. And it's not that they leave the spacecraft, it's that they become aware of where your units are, regardless of the actual fog of war / field of view. That doesn't always mean they'll come out to fight. I've had aliens stay in their spacecraft upwards of turn 30. (Sectoid Commander holed up in a control room, and my 'nauts had morale so low it was 3 turns of berserk / panic for every productive one).

Comment: It was turn 42 or 43 when I finally entered the ship, and the bugger was still in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm pretty sure you can't actually destroy the UFO walls with those weapons.

Have you tried having one person stay in the spot where they fell down and then have a second person go through the door?  I don't remember what happens, but it might let you walk over (since the second person wouldn't have anywhere to fall to).

Comment: Unfortunately, I saved another game in over the same slot, but I will certainly try this out later on. Thank you.